# How to take javascript user input on VS code console/terminal and return the input value

Tags: javascript, input, user-input

So, in python, we can assign a user input into a variable using the "input" function. Then how do we get user input in JavaScript?
if we use a html file, we can use the prompt() function but what if I want to take a user input inside my text-editor? and i don't want to import an external code (like node.js)

Any ideas on how to make that possible?

```
var name = input("Enter your name here");
```

I tried running the above code and its giving me a syntax error.
this code actually works in python.
I don't want to use prompt() because i want to take the user input from the command line.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have functionality for user input. It requires the API of the runtime environment to provide it. Which runtime environment do you use? Is it Node.js? Most browsers provide `prompt`. Node.js provides `readline`. Node.js is not external code. It's an alternative runtime environment to a browser.

Comment: `i don't want to import an external code (like node.js)`  But that's what you had to do with python, so you have to do with JS too.  A runtime is not going to magically appear..

Comment: Also the VS code terminal is just that, an integrated terminal running by default the same terminal shell as your system.

Answer (score -2):

You can try to use this module for your task https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html

```
import {
    stdin as input,
    stdout as output,
} from 'node:process';

const rl = readline.createInterface({ input, output });

const answer = await rl.question(
    'What do you think of Node.js? '
);

console.log(
    `Thank you for your valuable feedback: ${answer}`
);

rl.close();
```

Comment: I never down-voted, but you might find you got some for the OP saying -> `import -> (like node.js)`  and what you have shown is `node.js`..  To be fair the question was bad, and unfortunately you got caught up in the crossfire.